Can we call "an afternoon we hang out with our friends at a shopping mall" "an outing"?
According to some dictionaries, "outing" is "a short trip made by a group of people for entertainment/pleasure".
But the definition of "an outing" on Merriam-Webster is a brief usually outdoor pleasure trip. link
So, can an afternoon we hang out with our friends at a shopping mall (which means all the activities would be indoors) be called "an outing"?

Outdoor in this context simply means 'out of your home' so if I went on a bus to a big mall, either alone or with friends, and spent some time there, that would certainly be an 'outing'. In fact, if I had been at home (e.g. sick) for a while, and I recovered enough to walk 200 metres to the nearest shop, I could still reasonably call that an outing.

If it's fun, or a relief from being indoors, it's an outing.

And M-W says "usually" which means that is how the word is used most often, although not always.   I would add "usually during the day". I don't think a seance, or a rave, could be called an "outing".

I'm not sure if teenagers would say "outing", it sounds a bit more old-fashioned. What country, age, etc?

Well, I'm referring to those in their twenties, thirties @StuartF

I disagree that an outing has to be outdoors. You could have an outing that takes place indoors, or that's held both inside and outside. I don't think the "out" refers to "outside," but to the fact that everyone who attends will be "out of the house."
So to answer your question, an afternoon hanging out at the mall with friends would not be disqualified as an outing because it takes place indoors.
While an outing is often a more formal event that is planned and promoted, I stand corrected that it doesn't have to be. Regardless, it's probably not the word that a group of young adults might use to describe their afternoon at the mall.
Previously, I focused on the "hanging out" part of your sentence and suggested "get-together." But that's not equivalent to what outing focuses on, which is the "getting out of the house" part, not what you do when you get there.
So, going back to the definition from the dictionary, I suggest trip as an alternative to outing. For example:

The teenagers took a trip to the mall and hung out there all afternoon.

You can also be very informal and slightly sarcastic:

We went on a field trip to the mall this afternoon.
We had an adventure at the mall today.

Or, very informally:

We were on mall-duty this afternoon.


Thank you, sometimes I can't find the exact word I'm looking for in my mother tongue too. I'm also asking/finding a better alternative to "outing". If you can think of a better word, please let me know!

It may be a transatlantic difference, but I certainly wouldn't say that an outing has to be an organised excursion. You can go on a family outing to the seaside, or a 'little outing to the shops'.

Agreed. I thought more about this and modified my answer.
